# Is this a correct pcap filter expression

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap, wifi

```
const char *str = "wlan subtype assoc-req or wlan subtype probe-req or wlan subtype probe-resp";
struct bpf_program fp;

if((pcap_compile(pkt_handle, &fp, str, 1, PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN)==-1))
{
    pcap_perror(pkt_handle, "Compile");
}
else
    printf("filter compiled\n");
```

After running, the program displays "filter compiled", but it still captures Beacon frames and lots of other frames apart from the three mentioned in filter expression. 

So, is it the correct filter expression to catch only assoc-req, probe-req, probe-resp frames?

Comment: Are you calling `pcap_setfilter`?

Comment: @interjay Oh ... correct ... forgot to call pcap_setfilter ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As interjay said, you have to call `pcap_setfilter()` to make the filter take effect.  (Making it an answer so that the question shows up as *having* an answer.)